# Dimension of a unit square

Tags: cardinals, infinity

We all know the bijection between a unit square and a unit segment (see [this link](http://planetmath.org/bijectionbetweenunitintervalandunitsquare) for example).

Since I can thus represent every point of the square with only one number, does it mean that the square is of dimension 1? We know it is of dimension 2, so where is the bug?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by dimension?  How do you define the dimension of a space such as $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: Well, in fact it is a good question... Naively, I would say it corresponds to the number of coordinates that are necessary to identify a point in the space...

Answer (score 0):

Points on the line and points in the plane have the same *cardinality*. In your link, the decription says that the unit square is defined via the open interval $I=(0, 1)$ such that the square, $S = I \times I$, with obvious bijection between $I$ and $I \times I$.

Answer (score 0):

The 'bug' is that the specified bijection is not continuous.  If you require a continuous mapping between the unit square and unit segment, you will find that that is not possible.  THAT is where the dimensionality comes into play.

Comment: Thanks for this explaination. Could you just go further? What is the link between continuity of a mapping and the dimension ?

Comment: I do not know what do you mean. What about space filling curves? Like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve